# Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Need a small help , can someone point me what is the issue here .

What i am trying to achieve , the pipeline has to run checkout irrespective of the branch i am in , but in the build stage if the pipeline run from master it has execute some templet if from other branch different templet , i tried many option no luck .

Any pointer much appreciated .

```
- name: release
  displayName: ReleaseVersion
  type: string
  default: ' '

- name: Deployment
  displayName: DeploymentVersion
  type: string
  default: ' '


- name: Library
  displayName: Library Release
  type: boolean
  default: True

trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: DOTAzure-Ubuntu-20.04

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: azureTemplates
      type: githubenterprise
      name: AAAAA/azure-pipelines
      endpoint: BBBBBB

# You should add below variables to work complete pipeline
variables:
- name: servicename
  value: XXXXX
- name: countryCode
  value: YYYYY
- name: targetPort
  value: 8113

stages:
  - stage: Checkout
    displayName: Micro Service checkout and Secrets
    jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - template: templates/repocheckout.yml@azureTemplates

      - template: templates/retrieving_secrets.yml@azureTemplates

      - template: templates/Ingesting_secrets.yml@azureTemplates
      
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Microservice Build
    jobs:
    - job: Master
      condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') 
      steps:
      - template: templates/mavenbuild_new.yml@azureTemplates
      - template: templates/push_artifact_jfrog.yml@azureTemplates
        parameters:
          service_name: '$(countryCode)-$(servicename)'
          release_version: $(release)   
          
    - job: Develop
      dependsOn: Master
      condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop')
      steps:
      - template: templates/mavenbuild.yml@azureTemplates
      - template: templates/push_artifact_jfrog.yml@azureTemplates
        parameters:
          service_name: '$(countryCode)-$(servicename)'
          release_version: $(release)
```

Comment: share the error you got

Comment: ```
/templates/push_artifact_jfrog.yml@azureTemplates (Line: 1, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'stages'```

Comment: i have this error,thanks

Comment: the template should contains steps and not stages

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like valid yaml.

[image: Stages yaml]

Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema

It looks like you are missing this at the top of the file:

stages:

i.e. your yaml should be:

```html
stages:
  - stage: Checkout
    displayName: Micro Service checkout and Secrets
    jobs:
```

etc

Comment: i changed the code but still the same error , please see the orginal question

Comment: please add the full yaml file.  it seems you have left some bits out, so it is difficult to help

Comment: sure , i changed the original code